# Multiple levels of indirection in C

Tags: c, pointers

In an **effort to really grasp** pointers in C, I was experimenting with multiple levels of indirection. I understand the basics:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void indirection(int * n)
{
    *n = 3;
}

int main ()
{
    int n;

    indirection(&n);
    printf("Your number is %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

But I want to take it to the extreme and want to write the function:

```
void indirection(int ****n)
{
   ****n = 3;
}
```

to set the value of `n`, and print it in `main`, but I keep getting segmentation fault and other errors.

So how should I declare `n` in main, and how to use its value?

Comment: *"But I want to take it to the extreme and want to write the function:"* - Trust me. You don't want to do that.

Comment: _"All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection"_ - (Butler Lampson).  But you have to have a problem that needs solving!  There is a corollaryt to Lampson that says _"...except for the problem of too many layers of indirection._" .  Let's be sensible now! ;-)

Comment: @klutt Pretty sure I do want to do it. I'm not writing production code, the point here is just learn. (effort to really grasp)

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi Yes, I understand that. Was just making a point that you really should avoid indirection unless necessary. One or two stars is ok, but if you need three, you should probably rethink what you're doing.

Comment: And in this case, `f(int *n)` is used when you want to change a variable like you're doing. `f(int **n)` is used when you want to change the pointer that's passed to it.

Comment: @klut: Point taken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter type of `indirection()` function is `int ****` i.e. pointer to pointer to pointer to pointer to an `int` which is nothing but address of a `int ***` type variable. So,

`int ****` type variable can hold address of `int ***` type variable.

`int ***` type variable can hold address of `int **` type variable.

`int **` type variable can hold address of `int *` type variable.

`int *` type variable can hold address of `int` type variable.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void indirection(int ****n) {
    ****n = 3;
}

int main (void) {
    int n = 0;
    int *p1 = &n;
    int **p2 = &p1;
    int ***p3 = &p2;

    indirection (&p3);

    printf ("Your number is %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Easy to understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pointers must point to something (an *object*), not just a value, so you cannot create them “on the fly” using multiple `&` operators. To get a pointer to a pointer, you must first define a pointer and then take its address. To get further pointers, you must repeat this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void indirection(int ****n)
{
    ****n = 3;
}

int main(void)
{
    int     n;
    int    *np  = &n;
    int   **npp = &np;
    int ***nppp = &npp;

    indirection(&nppp);
    printf("Your number is %d.\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

That said, there is a way to create objects on the fly, using compound literals. This works because a compound literal is not a normal operand that evaluates some operation but is a way of creating a temporary object:

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    indirection(& (int ***) { & (int **) { & (int *) { &n } } });
    printf("Your number is %d.\n", n);
}
```

Comment: Good answer too. I just couldn't compile the compound literal that you mention.

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi: Are you compiling as C or C++? With what compiler and version?

Comment: C, Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi: Compound literals work in C with Apple Clang. What error message did you get?

Answer (score 1):

You have not shown how you are calling the modified `indirection()` but the seg-fault is almost certainly down to how you are calling the function.

If you are calling it as in the original `main()` you should get a warning:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘indirection’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

and it will most likely seg-fault as you have observed.  The waring is telling you something about the semantics of your code.

I am not going to bend my brain around this frankly ill-advised effort.  Lets take a simpler case:

```
void indirection(int** n)
{
   **n = 3;
}
```

If you can get that working you can extrapolate step-by-step to higher levels of indirection.

A call to this might look like:

```
    int n ;
    int* pn = &n ;

    indirection( &pn ) ;

    printf( "Your number is %d\n", n ) ;
```

To add a further level of indirection you'd instantiate a another level pointer:

```
    int n ;
    int* pn = &n ;
    int** ppn = &pn ;
```

The point is at each level you need something concrete to point to.  You cannot for example just add `&`s, for example:

```
indirection(&&n);
```

because while `&n` - address-of `n` makes sense; `&&n` address-of-address-of `n` does not because `&n` is not a stored variable with an address to take.  IT will not in fact compile.

That is the how - I'll leave the why to you.